# Singleton variable turns empty after switching views

Tags: swift, singleton

I made a singleton class to access my user's email from any other class for easy upload of data to cloud. I am able to print the email in the first view but when i try to access it in other views or come back to this view, it shows up as empty.

```
class SingletonAccount: NSObject {

static var shared: SingletonAccount = SingletonAccount()
var userEmail: String = "ABCD"

}
```

I also set the singleton to be initialised only in the appDelegate so that it could be shared among all the other classes.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var userAccount: SingletonAccount?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        userAccount = SingletonAccount.shared
        return true
    }
```

Below is the first view controller that appears on launch

```
weak var userAccount: SingletonAccount?


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true

        print(userAccount!.userEmail)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LoginViewController.tapRegister))
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        userAccount = appDelegate.userAccount
        self.registerLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The benefit of a singleton is to have access to the same instance from everywhere.

Declaring a property in `AppDelegate` is pointless. Just get the mail address with

```
let email = SingletonAccount.shared.userEmail
```

And declare `shared` as constant. The description *Singleton* implies a constant.

```
static let shared = SingletonAccount()
```

And it's not necessary that the class inherits from `NSObject`, it's not even necessary that the singleton is a class.

Answer (score 0):

you're declaring a new instance of userAccount in your view controller. if you have to use the var in appDelegate do

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let aVariable = appDelegate.userAccount
```

i would just always use SingletonAccount.shared. Or define you singleton globally outside of the SingletonAccount class

```
let gSingletonAccount: SingletonAccount = SingletonAccount()
class SingletonAccount: NSObject {
var userEmail: String = "ABCD"
}
```